# PHPのLocationのURLに日本語URLを指定してリダイレクトする方法

Tags: php

phpのheader関数でリダイレクトの指定をしているのですが、
http://example.com/あいうえお/かきくけこ
などの日本語が入っているURLにリダイレクトされません。

```
$redirect =  'http://example.com/あいうえお/かきくけこ';

if(!empty($redirect)){
    header("Location: 0; URL= ".$redirect );
}
```

どなたかご教示いただければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

２箇所を修正する必要があります。一つはuworkさん指摘 urlencoe、もう一つはLocationヘッダの書式です。0; URL= はMETA refreshの際の書式ですので、Locationヘッダを使う場合は直にURLを書きます。
以下の様な感じになります。

```
$redirect =  'http://example.com/' . urlencode('あいうえお') . '/' . urlencode('かきくけこ');

if(!empty($redirect)){
    header("Location: ".$redirect );
}
```

Comment: ソースまで記入していただき、ありがとうございます。
無事動作しました。

Answer (score 0):

日本語の部分をurlencode関数でURL用にエンコードしてやれば大丈夫かと思います。

Comment: uworkさんのご指摘の通りでしたが、あわせてheader関数の指摘をしていただきましたockeghemさんにベストアンサーをさせていただきました。
ありがとうございます。